# Assign a FrameworkElement to a control template programatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controltemplate

I'm trying to custom draw a GridSplitter, and I have the following XAML code:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <GridSplitter.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
            <custom:DiffSplitterCanvas />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </GridSplitter.Template>
</GridSplitter>
```

`DiffSplitterCanvas` inherits from `Canvas`.

I need to write it **programatically**. And I also need it to use a given **already created instance** of the `DiffSplitterCanvas`. Simplifying the code, it would be something like this:

```
GridSplitter mySplitter = new GridSplitter();
ControlTemplate myTemplate = new ControlTemplate(typeof(GridSplitter));
DiffSplitterCanvas myCanvas = new DiffSplitterCanvas();
AddElementToTemplate(myCanvas, myTemplate);
mySplitter.Template = myTemplate;

void AddElementToTemplate(FrameworkElement element, ControlTemplate template)
{
  // how could achieve this?
}
```

**EDIT:** The reason I ask this question is because I need to change some properties in the DiffSplitterCanvas instance while the user interacts with the UI. Maybe this is not the way to implement it using WPF, but I'm really lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use bindings and dependency properties. You could do this in pure procedural code, but this will be over-complicated and error-prone.

You can get an overview of dependency properties in the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx). There is also [some good tutorials](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html).

Assuming you declare a dependency property called `MyProperty` in `DiffSplitterCanvas`, in the end you will have something like:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <GridSplitter.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
            <custom:DiffSplitterCanvas
                 MyProperty="{Binding Path=SomeOtherPropertyFromDataContext}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </GridSplitter.Template>
</GridSplitter>
```

Whenever the value of `SomeOtherPropertyFromDataContext` changed it will be reflected on the `DiffSplitterCanvas`. Note that you will need to configure the `Source` attribute of the binding accordingly, depending on what is holding the `SomeOtherPropertyFromDataContext` property (might be the context of the column, the parent control, the view model, etc.).

Comment: Hi Kryptos, please, could you write here a working example? I was unable to assign the `SomeOtherPropertyFromDataContext` to my GridSplitterCanvas. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well. I kind of already is a working example... Of course `SomeOtherPropertyFromDataContext` is just an arbitrary name. With the user interacting with the UI you will get events and change some properties. So if you have a DataContext  with a property named `SomeOtherPropertyFromDataContext`, when you change programatically the value of this property, it will also change the value of `MyProperty` thanks to the binding. What to need to do is define the `SomeOtherPropertyFromDataContext` somewhere and make sure it is an accessible datacontext for where you put your `DiffSplitterCanvas`.